# How do I politely remind my boss about his decision?

Tags: job-offer, internship

I am currently working as an intern at a mid-range startup. After the end of my first internship period , since the project that I am doing here got good results, my boss asked me to extend the internship. During that discussion he also told me the company is ready to give me a full-time role , and agreed that they will sponsor my H1B (as an international student working in the US , H1B is necessary after my OTP expires). He also agreed a certain pay (that in my opinion is good) . Last week I reminded him about the offer letter, and asked him to let me know the decision soon. He told he would let me know by this week. But I still have not heard from him about this yet. How do I remind him politely about this ? If,for some reason, they don't want to extend the offer , then I need to apply to the other companies. Given the current situation of economy ,I know job-hunt is going to be tough and I need his decision as soon as possible. Also I have only about couple of weeks remaining in my internship.

Comment: It is still "by this week"... so if you follow up do it after such time expires (weeks start on sunday/monday).

Comment: Can you clarify if you received a written offer letter or a verbal offer? How much time has elapsed since the original offer and the reminder last week? As a side point, it would be prudent to plan and execute your job hunt regardless of what you're told until you have the confirmed offer received and accepted.

Comment: @DavidS , it was the verbal offer, and it's been roughly 2 months. I am starting the job hunt regardless

Comment: Given the news about US tech layoffs this week, it's also possible that your boss thought he had a job lined up for you, had hired interns that way before, but suddenly the job's not there any more, and he's not really being told about it because the executive layer above him is getting much funnier about hiring, when previously they were all go go go ...

Comment: @McLovin, Yes, you really screwed up by waiting this long. Also, in the future, memorialize important conversations after the fact over email. Not that this changes anything. When looking for a job, you should always apply to as many employers as you can.

Answer (score 16):

You MUST make alternative plans starting right now. Even if your boss is well intended and they actually want to hire you, you still have to go through the H1B process which can take many years.

Filing for H1B is relatively simple and the approval rate is generally good, however the number of applications significantly exceeds the number of number of available Visas and hence they execute each year the dreaded H1B lottery. For 2022 they predict an about a 4:1 ratio, so only 25% of all applicants will actually get a Visa. For the rest it's "try again next year" with similar chances.

You can't put your life and career on hold to wait this out.

To clarify: your boss CAN'T give you an offer to start in 3 weeks. They can only give you an offer that's contingent on you getting authorization to work in the US and to sponsor an H1B. Ideally that process should have started a long time ago, so you chances of getting even just a contingent offer are not great.

Answer (score 5):

> If,for some reason, they don't want to extend the offer , then I need
> to apply to the other companies. Given the current situation of
> economy ,I know job-hunt is going to be tough and I need his decision
> as soon as possible. Also I have only about couple of weeks remaining
> in my internship.

Don't wait for an answer. Apply to other places. If you get the answer you want in a few weeks, and they give you an official written offer with no conditions that you accept, sign, and return; then you can pause the other searches.

When time is short don't hesitate to search for other opportunities. If they give you a verbal confirmation, keep looking.

> But I still have not heard from him about this yet. How do I remind
> him politely about this ?

So next week, ask your boss. Ask what the next step is to move to a full time role. You can ether ask in person, or just a quick note.

Answer (score 2):

Your boss may have to discuss your position with HIS boss and with accounting just to make sure you can be paid what was offered. People are busy so this takes time.

In the meantime you can still apply to other jobs, just don't take them yet.

You can also ask your boss after 1 week has passed "How is the paperwork going for my full time position? Should I apply for other jobs just in case?" This will put pressure on him by telling him you have other options and will tell him you are interested in still working there.